# What can we conclude about the coefficients of Laurent expansion for two functions being equal on the real axis?

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Consider two functions $f(z)$ and $g(\bar{z})$ where $z=x+iy$ and $\bar{z} = x-iy$. It is given that these functions admit a Laurent expansion around $z=0$ as $$f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} f_n z^n \quad g(\bar{z}) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}g_n \bar{z}^n$$ It is also given that these functions are equal on the real axis i.e. $$f(z) = g(\bar{z}) \text{ for } z = \bar{z}$$
What can we conclude about the relation between the coefficients $f_n$ and $g_n$? Would $f_n=g_n$ hold $\forall n\in Z$?

In other words, if the Laurent expansion (around $z=0$) of two complex functions is equal on the real axis, can we equate the coefficients?

Comment: @Conrad Why do you say $f=h$ on the real axis? The coefficients $f_n$ could be complex numbers.

Comment: good point  - you indeed get $f_n=g_n$ as $h(z)=\sum g_nz^n$ is analytic on the punctured plane and satisfies $f=h$ on the real axis

Comment: @Conrad That is a clever trick. Could you please write it in the answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: no problem - done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h(z)= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}g_n {z}^n$; by hypothesis $h$ is analytic nn the punctured plane and $f=h$ on the real axis, so $f=h$ everywhere, hence $f_n=g_n$